# Prime to Prime change

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Change the Prime Number 71549 to another Prime Number 10067 in Five steps by changing one digit at a time.

Every time you change the digit **the new number must be a Prime Number also**. You cannot rearrange the digits after the change.

No programming please

Comment: No computers? You want us to check multiple 5-digit numbers for primality by hand? Hmmmm.

Comment: Point taken will edit

Comment: Well -- it might turn out that we can "prune" enough by spotting e.g. multiples of 3, 7, 11 that substantial computation isn't needed...

Comment: I was not smart enough to realize the data base may exist. Did it by what you call "prune" method

Comment: If the original number is 12345 then first step could be 13345. Second could be 13375. So you are changing 1 digit at a time only.

Comment: Grats on 1k! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's <s>one</s> the only way (changed number in bold):

> 71549 -> 715**6**9 -> 71**0**69 -> **1**1069 -> 1**0**069 -> 1006**7**

**Steps taken**

First number change:

> The only possible (read: still prime) switches are **1**1549, 7**0**549, and 715**6**9

Second number change:

> 11549 does not have any possible moves, so that number will not work. The same goes for 70549. Therefore, the only number from the first move that still applies is 71569. The only number that is still prime is 71**0**69.

Third number change:

> Taking 71069, the only possible move is **1**1069.

Fourth number change:

> Taking 11069, only 1**0**069 works.

Last number change:

> We move on the 1006**7**, the final prime. There are no other ways to get to this number from 71549, changing only one number at a time AND keeping every intermediate value prime.

Comment: Did you check the computer for Prime data base Moose?

Comment: FWIW, this is also the solution I found. That doesn't necessarily mean it's the only one -- it could just mean that we tried things in the same order.